# How to bind string in square bracket?

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

I'm using like this:  `master.Name=entity.Name;` // let it be `Prashant`

I want to append Name in Square bracket Like `[Prashant]`

Comment: Do not use the word "bind" in question title. This word has a specific meaning in .NET's context and is not used for appending characters to strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Old way of doing that would be:

```
master.Name = '[' + entity.Name + ']';
```

A relatively better way is:

```
master.Name = string.Format("[{0}]", entity.Name);
```

And if you're using C# 6.0 or above:

```
master.Name = $"[{entity.Name}]";
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Name` as a property in class `Master` and use it's getter for do this job:

```
private string _Name;

public string Name
{
    get { return "[" + _Name + "]"; } // Or String.Format("[{0}]",_Name)
    set { _Name = value; }
}
```

So that when ever you access `master.Name` it will give you the output in desired format. ie., `[Prashant]`

Usage example is added [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/N8RC9A) Or else format them whenever you use those properties like this:

```
 Console.WriteLine(String.Format("[{0}]",masterInstace.Name));
```

Comment: Great , Thank you  :)

Comment: @un-lucky, do not write properties this way. Consider this code: `obj.Name = "Foo"; Debug.Assert(obj.Name == "Foo");`

Comment: I am not a question owner but I am also coming with the same answer as you posted.

Comment: hi lucky, but cant write class as you mentioned because this property used in various function. can you please provide another answer?